# LaTeX via VS Code, macOS, solving 'Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT.' error

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, path, latex, vscode-extensions

- I am running macOS
- VS Code is installed and working
- I have installed LaTeX Workshop
- I have installed MacTeX
- I get a '**Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT.**' error when trying to compile a LaTeX document in VS Code

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Install#setting-path-environment-variable) I understand that I need to set the PATH environment variable. However I do not understand (1) what this means, and (2) how to do. I have followed the links in the documentation but I have not been able to resolve my issue.

Can anyone assist with a simplified explanation of the steps required to set the PATH?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error: `Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT.`

The steps I took to solve my problem on macOS (Ventura 13.3.1), with MacTeX-2023 was:

1. Within VSCode:
   a. `cmd+shift+P`, select `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`.
2. Then within the json, paste the following within the {}:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.path": "/Library/TeX/texbin",
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
         "name": "latexmk",
         "command": "latexmk",
         "args": [
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "-pdf",
          "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
          "%DOC%"
         ],
         "env": {}
        },
        {
         "name": "xelatex",
         "command": "xelatex",
         "args": [
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "%DOC%"
         ],
         "env": {}
        },
        {
         "name": "pdflatex",
         "command": "pdflatex",
         "args": [
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "%DOC%"
         ],
         "env": {}
        },
        {
         "name": "bibtex",
         "command": "bibtex",
         "args": [
          "%DOCFILE%"
         ],
         "env": {}
        }
       ],
       "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
         "name": "pdfLaTeX",
         "tools": [
          "pdflatex"
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "latexmk ",
         "tools": [
          "latexmk"
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "xelatex",
         "tools": [
          "xelatex"
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex`×2",
         "tools": [
          "pdflatex",
          "bibtex",
          "pdflatex",
          "pdflatex"
         ]
        },
        {
        "name": "xelatex ➞ bibtex ➞ xelatex`×2",
        "tools": [
          "xelatex",
          "bibtex",
          "xelatex",
          "xelatex"
         ]
        }
       ]
```

3. Ensure `"latex-workshop.latex.path": "/Library/TeX/texbin"` reflects your MacTeX installation. If you followed the default prompts when installing the .pkg of MacTeX, then the path I specified *should* be the same.
4. Restart Visual Studio Code.
   a. I found that reloading the window with the `Developer: Reload Window` command was not enough, I needed to quit Visual Studio Code and open again.
5. Try out the following in a test file, within a new .tex file (`File > New File > test.tex`):
   (I took this MWE from Overleaf)

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Welcome to Overleaf --- just edit your LaTeX on the left,
% and we'll compile it for you on the right. If you open the
% 'Share' menu, you can invite other users to edit at the same
% time. See www.overleaf.com/learn for more info. Enjoy!
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
        name=latex,
        description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=mathematics,
        description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
        name=formula,
        description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are 
rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This 
process is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.

\clearpage



%\printglossary

\end{document}
```

6. Finally, within VSCode:

   1. Select the TeX Workshop Extension in the left sidebar
   2. Select the drop-down arrow to the left of `Build LaTeX project`
   3. Click the recipe: `Recipe: pdfLaTeX`

Answer (score 0):

What you should try is the following.

1. Use `win + x` shortcut or go to Windows settings and select **System**.
2. From there, select **advanced system settings**.
3. Now you should select **Environment variables**.
4. You'll see two parts of the windows, the top part with user-based environment variables and the bottom part with system ones. You're gonna find **PATH** in both of them and do the following :
5. Select **PATH** and clic **Modify**.
6. Clic **New** and add the path to your LaTeX distribution, for example : `C:\texlive\2021`

If you do that, it should work, it worked at installation in my case cause I already added these entries to the **PATH**.

**EDIT:** I must be tired, I just realized you are using Mac OS. I will let my Windows answer for other people, but the steps must look alike.